# Google API on Libre Office suddenly doesn't give info

Tags: geolocation, google-api, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I have been working with Libre Office for a while now. I have this huge database from which I have to find the coordinates for each given address given there. I was using the GeoLocate API found on [this site](http://www.digital-geography.com/geocoding-addresses-directly-in-libreoffice-calc/#.VAh1ZvmSx8E). However, suddenly, the macro doesn't give results. It worked perfectly fine before that. The code is on the site. Any help would be great.

Comment: Have you read this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/geolocation/#usage_limits ?

Answer (score 0):

English is not my native language so please be patient.

From the [official page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro#usage_limits) for Developers, check the usage limit:

[image]